# Azure - Use of dynamically generated Auth-token in Load Test requests

Tags: azure-devops, load-testing

I'm quite new to Azure/AzureDevOps and its LoadTest app.
I need to execute a Load Test for a scenario where I login as a user and execute a few requests while logged in. 
The original request is returning auth-token in its Response, that auth-token is used as one of the parameters for the Header in all other sequential Requests.

What I cannot figure out (nor find on the Internet) is to:
1. How to get the auth-token in the 1st Response;
2. How to use this token (dynamically) in all other Requests in the Load Test.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you intended to run a web test against your web application.

have you created your load test project with Visual Studio?

As for getting the auth-token and using it in other requests,I don't think it is achievable with azure devops load test app. 
I believe it should be done in your web test code.

You can create your web test which introduced in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-web-service-test?view=vs-2017) or write your test in code with selenium or other tools. Add add the web test to a [load test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/quickstart-create-a-load-test-project?view=vs-2017) project. To deal with the dynamic parameters which cannot be detected by your web request in your test,you can check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/fix-non-detectable-dynamic-parameters-in-a-web-performance-test?view=vs-2017).

After you have created your load test project.  You can upload your load test to azure devops load test shown as below pic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Levi Lu-MSFT. Let me look into this info and give a try.

Comment: @KVN  how is going with this case? was above information of any help?

Comment: Sorry @Levi Lu-MSFT, I got a bit sidetracked with work on more simple cases (without auth). Will look into the above one this or next week.Thanks once again.

Comment: Thanks @Levi Lu-MSFT that what I need. Now just need to figure out how to implement it for my test/pages.